# Shiny Rmarkdown Hyperlink to local PDF

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server, dt

I'm running an Rmarkdown Document with a Shiny Flexdashboard Output on my shiny server. 
I'm creating a DT table where one column should be a link to a PDF file stored on my server at

```
/etc/srv/shiny-server/AppFolder/www/file.pdf
```

The code for the table looks like this :

```
datatable(query_result_table,escape = FALSE)
```

where query_result_table holds the following text string in a column :

```
"<a href='http://myservername.co.uk:3838/AppFolder/www/file.pdf' target='_blank' >MyFile</a>"
```

DT does render a link however, when clicking, I get a "Not Found" page. I've tried the following things :

- Modified permissions of www and file.pdf to 777 with no effect
- Modified the href part of the link to href = 'file.pdf' with no effect

I've thoroughly researched the literature on this issue and the solution usually provided is to create a www folder in the shiny root directory however this does not seem to work in my case, perhaps because this is an Rmd document rather than a ui.R / server.R document couple.

Has anyone resolved this problem before ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You may consider to put the file under /usr/share so it can be accessed publically

Answer (score 0):

I have finally rewritten my app in proper shiny format, that is a ui.R and Server.R document couple. The app then successfully accesses the PDF files in the www folder. More generally, there is more flexibility and online literature for the ui.R/server.R format than for .Rmd when it comes to building app so it is a preferable format albeit with a slightly steeper learning curve for synthax.